# "Analyze" --> "Space" Revit 2024

Tags: revit-api

I have an electrical plan template but when I go to the "analyze" tab, the "space" option to choose the environments does not appear and, as a result, I cannot access the electrical properties of the room. Do you know how I can solve the problem?

i tried click in this tab, but not appear the optin "space"

Comment: I'm not sure that this is actually about programming.  This sounds like it might be a better fit for the [electrical engineering stack exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Fully agree, does not sounds ike a programming question. I would suggest taking recourse to the non-API  [Autodesk Revit discussion forums](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-products/ct-p/2003). Maybe the MEP one is the best fit for this question.